# Managing hierarchical tasks with module/mediator/facade pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, architecture

Say I've got a very intensive programatic task to complete, `big task`, which can broken down into smaller well-defined sub-tasks:

- `big task`

  - `small task 1`

    - `tiny task 1`
    - `tiny task 2`
    - `...`
  - `small task 2`

    - `...`
  - `...`

Each sub-task takes data from the parent task, runs the relevant calculations, and then returns the result to the parent, and so on through the tree until `big task` is completed.

I'm still learning about the module/mediator/facade pattern, but as far as I understand, the architecture would look like this:

[image: Hierarchical module/mediator/facade setup]

Parent tasks would publish instructions (which sub-tasks hear), and sub-tasks would publish their results on completion (which parent tasks would hear).

Is my understanding correct? [Addy Osmani](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#mediatorpatternjavascript)'s explanations have been immensly helpful, but he doesn't talk too much about modules that are for complex series of calculations. Maybe there's a better design pattern for this type of project? Thanks.

Comment: Not a javascript programmer but one way of doing this would be to implement blocking queues at each level. Although, I am not sure if javascript provides data structures such as queues.

Comment: Thanks bot, I haven't heard of queues in JS, but I'm sure I could implement something if it came to it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you really need to use so much design patterns here?

If you have just a series of nested isolated tasks, why not to structure them like [matryoshka doll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll)?

You may have one abstract Task class, which allows itself to have children. There can be no children also. This class may have also calc() function, that starts children for calculations if needed, combines results and returns some value to parent. You will have to abstract some logic into Task, but such scheme will allow you to lower complexity.

You will then have specific descendants of Task to perform calculations of different kinds. You can store configuration of such tasks in JSON or XML file.

Using various patterns looks very beautiful and cool, but if their use is not needed at all...

Do I miss something?

Comment: Hey, you've given me some good thinking points, thanks. My app is much more complex than just a single hierarchical task, so I'll definitely need to use a design pattern, but maybe you're right that I could do even large calculations in a single module that has 'nested' dependancies. I'm not entirely sure how this would work though...

Comment: FractalizeR is describing Composite pattern here. Take a look at https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns#composite for an example.

Comment: @JoeRocc you are welcome. I never saw your application in a whole so I can't suggest something very concrete. But the basic idea is to write code that does the most simple thing possible (described by someone as a "pattern" or not - it doesn't matter). Don't rush for using OOP patterns for just the sake of it.